# Remember Me option not worked in Yii 1.6

Tags: php, yii, remember-me

My application developed in Yii 1.6.
when i logged in system using Url : mysite.com/admin/login 
and check remember Me check box ,its successfully logged in enter admin dashboard.

In admin dashboard i have just showed current user email id fetching from session .
When i closed browse again open site ,its show error like below.

[image]

Error is happen do to i checked remember me button yii 1.6 session will remember some days. when i print `Yii::app()->user->id`  its show user id last logged in that browser .but email ID other item cant get from session.